# Sort documents based on a collection of nested objects

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I would like to sort my documents based on nested attributes on them.
Given I have the following documents:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "value": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "value": 2
        }
    ]
}

{
    "id": 2,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "a",
            "value": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "b",
            "value": 2
        }
    ]
}

{
    "id": 3,
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "b",
            "value": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

The sorting should compare the values of the same attributes, so it should first go ahead and compare the values of the attribute "a".

If the values of group "a" are the same, it should then go ahead and compare attribute "b".

If the whole group is missing, the document missing the attribute should lose the comparison.

The attributes can have any names and values, so there's no knowledge of the attribute names beforehand.

I have written this algorithm in my client application, I just need a way to do this using ElasticSearch.

Comment: Do you know anything about how many attributes there are? And how do you define the order in which each attribute is considered?

Comment: I don't know how many attributes there are beforehand. The order in which attributes are compared should be alphabetically by the name of the attributes.

Comment: Then I don't think you can do this with ES.

Comment: Could I do it somehow if I stored my data in another way?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing it in two queries.  None of the below is tested, it's merely intended to give you a direction to consider.

The first query is an aggregation to get a distinct list of `attribute.name`

The second contains your actual query, with something like the following for `sort` (you'll have to build this sort based on the results of the above agg)

```
{
    "query": {"match_all": {}},
    "sort": [
        {
            "attributes.value": {
                "nested_path": "attributes",
                "nested_filter": {"term": {"attributes.name": "a"}}
            }
        }, 
        {
            "attributes.value": {
                "nested_path": "attributes",
                "nested_filter": {"term": {"attributes.name": "b"}}
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```